# Using \begin{rule} as theorem-like environment

Tags: macros, environments

I tried using `amsthm`and `thmtools` to define a theorem-like environment called `rule`. Turns out this is a bad idea, as `amsthm` then tries to define `\rule` and `\@rule`.

Now, the correct solution is obviously to call the environment `Rule` or something else, but I was wondering if there is a work-around.

My current progress is to do something like

```
\let\oldrule\rule
\let\oldatrule\@rule
\let\rule\undefined
\let\@rule\undefined

\declaretheorem{rule}

\let\newrule\rule
\let\newatrule\@rule
\let\rule\oldrule
\let\@rule\oldatrule
```

and then doing something like

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{rule}{%
    \let\rule\newrule
    \let\@rule\newatrule}
\AtEndEnvironment{rule}{%
    \let\rule\oldrule
    \let\@rule\newatrule}
```

This kind of works, as long as you are not using `\rule` as a line inside the environment. Is there a way to make this work even if I want to do this?

I am wondering mostly out of academic interest, and agree that anything like this should not be done in any actual document ever.

Comment: `\rule[]{}{}` may be used inside various construction where you did not even know it. So don't do this. It is kind of in the same category as messing with `\span` just  because you wanted the span operator from linear algebra. If you do not have 100% control over where a macro is used, don't mess with it, write your own name.

Comment: As mentioned, I am aware it's a horrible idea. The question is if it's possible, not if it's advisable.

Comment: Depends on what you call possible.  Getting it to work once for a particular example?  Yes.  Having it work in general?  No.